# unauthorized on npm install action

Tags: node.js, npm

I've logged in my private npm repository successfully. However, when I'm trying to install a package from it, npm is telling me: `"Unauthorized You must log in to perform this action.: npm"`. Any ideas?

1. `npm --registry http://private.registry.com/npm/npm_unstable login` -> `"Logged in as user on http://private.registry.com/npm/npm_unstable."`
2. `npm --registry http://private.registry.com/npm/npm_unstable install cest`

The content of `.npmrc`:

```
http://private.registry.com/npm/npm_unstable=
//private.registry.com/npm/:_password="TDVuZRndGwwMD8="
//private.registry.com/npm/:username=user
//private.registry.com/npm/:email=user@private-registry.com
//private.registry.com/npm/:always-auth=false
```

Comment: can you tell what is in your .npmrc

Comment: I've just added the content on post.

Comment: remove //private.registry.com/npm/:_password="TDVuZRndGwwMD8="
  from file and try